# Why the comments of other questions not considered as reliable answer?

Tags: discussion

I have answered the [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113882/does-neighbor-really-means-those-who-live-close/113883#113883) today and somebody down-voted me just because instead of copying the answer that i found useful answer in the [commets](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28604/why-rhea-is-translated-as-neighbor) of another question  so I provided the link the that particular question so it can be more clear to understand.But after sometime i got the comment that the comments of another question cannot be considered as reliable answer to make my point.

Should i directly copy and paste  that answer or  try it would be better to provide link to  answer.I always thought the priority is to solve the question at that time.

Comment: Comments get deleted regularly--using them as a source will lead to dead links eventually.

Comment: @simchona So why do so many regular contributors - including yourself in this particular instance - use comments to answer a question, if those comments may well subsequently be deleted?

Answer (score 4):

Answers that merely contain links are generally not considered answers, on Stack Exchange, even when the link is to another question on the same site. Links to comments are not reliable, since comments can be deleted in any moment, especially if the content of the linked comment is rewritten as answer, or incorporated into an existing answer.

If you want to answer the question, report what said in those comments, possibly giving the right attribution to who wrote those comments. You can also give a link to the first of the comments, but only after you wrote what those comments said.
In this way, the answer would still be an answer even when the comments are deleted.